# Does Evince support javascript in pdf files?

Tags: pdf, evince, javascript

In some pdf file readers for MS Windows such as those from Adobe or Foxit, it is possible to turn off the ability to implement javascript in a pdf file. Is that possible with Evince (Document Viewer) 3.2.1? I don't see any option to do so.

Or, is it that Evince does not implement javascript in pdf files at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, it doesn't support it, so you can't turn it off.

Comment: I also searched the net and came across a Nabble thread (http://old.nabble.com/-evince--what-missing-functionality-is-this-document-using--td30713693.html) to the same effect with the mention that the team is looking at supporting javascript

Answer (score 2):

**[update 05.2018]**: bug moved over to [gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/issues/24).

There is a [bug report on this on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338721).
It is classified as *Normal Enhancement*.
Unfortunately I have no clue if they are actively working on it or not..

Comment: The [upstream poppler bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14433) noted in March 2017 that "we already "support" Javascript, i.e. extract its contents" and posted a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-zmHc3WUhs) demonstrating "partial support" in Okular (the KDE poppler wrapper), so it is conceivable that Evince can gain this support in the future, though it'd be harder than for Okular (since Okular is a KDE app, it uses Qt, which has a [built-in JS interpreter](https://wiki.qt.io/JavaScript)). I hope they disable JS by default; it's too easy to abuse with **malware**.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, evince does not support Javascript.

---

**How to verify this?**

To make it easier for others to verify the up-to-dateness of this answer, you can query two information sources:

1. There exists an official bug report ([Support Javascript in PDF Documents](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338721)) handling the feature request for Javascript, which - by now - does not mention a version for which the Javascript support is planned:

   > `Version:     unspecified`
   >    `[...]`
   >   `Importance:  Normal enhancement`
2. Look at the official [roadmap of evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Roadmap), especially at the Javascript line from [Roadmap#Unresourced](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Roadmap#Unresourced):
   [image: Evince Roadmap - Unresourced - Highlight Javascript Status]

Answer (score -1):

Try PDF Studio, a free PDF reader / annotator and form filler that supports JavaScript for formatting, computing and validating.

https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/